# Come to ～: ～てくる vs. ～ようになる

Tags: grammar, nuances

Can someone please explain the fine nuances of these two?  Things such as:

- Are there conditions/restrictions of when you can use one or the other?
- What are the "approximate" time periods that each covers?
- Anything else relevant...

Here's an example I saw on a particular website.

> - 最近Xの機能を**使ってきた**みたい、ね！　→　What it actually said
> - 最近Xの機能を**使うようになった**みたい、ね！　→　What I thought it should have said

Comment: I agree with you; 最近Xの機能を使ってきた sounds incorrect to me.  最近Xの機能を使うようになった is fine.

Comment: @istrasci: Out of context, it's difficult to explain the fine nuances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the *aspectuality* (or more specifically, *telicity*) of the predicate.

- With *telic* predicates like `現れる, 染まる`, the event described involves a change of state. There is a change within the event before and after this point. With such predicates, various forms have the meanings such as the following:

> 現れている (perfect)
>   現れてくる (gradually 現れる towards the point of view of the first person)
>   現れていく (gradually 現れる apart from the point of view of the first person)
>   * 現れるようになる (ungrammatical)

- With *atelic* predicates like `使う, 走る, 食べる`, the event described does not involve a change of state, and is homogeneous throughout  (unless there is a direct object indicating an endpoint such as `このボンベを使う, 100メートルを走る, おにぎりを一つ食べる`). With such predicates, various forms have the meanings such as the following:

> 使っている (progressive)
>   使ってくる (使う on the way or before coming)
>   使っていく (使う on the way or before going)
>   使うようになる (gradually/eventually come to 使う)

There is no fixed time period for `最近`. It depends on the context.

Comment: This helped me a lot, I often did the mistake with the telic predicate (learnt also what telic meant). Great answer

Answer (score 1):

I think (I'm not a native speaker!) that

1. `~てきた` has more than one way you can use it.

a) What you talk about is something you've not planned:

> やっと春がやってきた
>   'Finally, spring has come.'
>
> 熊ちゃんが出てくるアニメが増えてきた。
>   'Anime with Teddy bears in them have increased in number.'

b) Refer to an action that carries on til the time of speaking:

> 宿題をしてきた。/宿題を忘れて来た。
>   `I've done/forgotten my homework.' (What you'd say to your teacher in class.)

2.On the other hand, `~ようになる`　is what you say when the result you're referring to was planned and desired, for example:

> 泳げるようになった！
>   '(Yeah,) I can swim!' (after practicing it for a long time)

Hope this helps and hope native speaker will correct me if I said anything wrong.