# Is it possible to attach になる to a verb

Tags: verbs

Is it possible to attach になる to a verb. For example:

I got tired after table tennis ー　卓球やってから**疲れ（て）**‍になった

I am not sure how to link 疲れる to になる. Is this not possible in Japanese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is it possible to attach になる to a verb.*

No. なる only works with nouns and adjectives.

> 社員になる *become an employee*
>   元気になる *become fine*
>   重くなる *become heavy/ier*

なる appears in a verb form only as keigo.

> お書きになる < 書く

An expression that involves a verb and なる does exist, which is ～ようになる. But it stands for that an event starts to constantly happen, and not what you try to tell.

> 卓球やってから疲れるようになった
>   *I started easily getting tired after playing table tennis.*

Fortunately, however, most Japanese verbs denote change of state with the unmarked aspect.

> 疲れる *get tired*, *be exhausting*
>   疲れ**ている** *be tired*

Thus,

> 卓球やって疲れた *I got tired after table tennis*

---

**Bonus:**

Rewording 疲れる using synonyms that go along with なる is of course possible.

> 卓球やってへとへとになった
>   卓球をして疲労困憊になった
>   *I was exhausted after table tennis.*

Comment: What do you mean by "with the unmarked aspect"?

Comment: @Newbie Something like "no aspect element attached" in this context.

Comment: See also [Come to ～: ～てくる vs. ～ようになる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5499/78).